# Solved: When using `bind 127.0.0.1` how to connect to a Redis container on a docker network?

Tags: security

I am attempting to deploy my Quarkus app which uses Redis (6.2.6 because I use Redis-Graph) on a Digital Ocean VM.

Can anyone tell me how they secured their Redis when used in a container on a private docker network on a VM please?

My docker compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis/redis-stack-server:6.2.6-v9

    container_name: flowt-central-redis

    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

    networks:
      - flowt-net

  flowt-central:
    image: ghcr.io/my-docker-image/flowt-central-jvm:latest
    container_name: flowt-central

    # The rest is deleted for brevity ....

    networks:
      - flowt-net

volumes:
  redis_data:

networks:
  flowt-net:
    name: flowt-net
    driver: bridge
```

My Quarkus Redis Client uses `quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://flowt-central-redis:6379` connection.

In redis.conf if I comment out the `bind 127.0.0.1 -::1` and set `protected-mode no` (ie the insecure way) everything connects and my Quarkus app reads and writes to Redis. All good.

Of course, Redis is accessible to the outside world doing it this way because I disabled the bind and protected-mode.

If I reinstate them, Redis refuses the Quarkus connection: `Connection refused: flowt-central-redis/192.168.192.3:6379`. :-(

So, from my reading it looks like I need to set an IP address on my docker network so it is not randomly assigned then use that to connect to Redis, but maybe that is not right either.

I can't be the first person needing to do this but have not found any specific posts or docs about using bind in conjunction with a docker network. It is probably there but I have not found it, or more likely misunderstood what I was reading.

Can anyone tell me how they secured their Redis when used in a container on a private docker network on a VM please? Am I on the right track or completely misunderstanding?

Thanks,
Murray

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The root cause was my misunderstanding of the `bind` directive in redis.conf. I thought it was binding to the `host` loopback and in fact it binds to the `container` loopback, which is not what I want.

Furthermore, I thought that when a port was exposed in docker run / compose where the container was on a custom docker network, the port was exposed on the `network`, whereas it is actually exposed on the `host`, whether or not the container is on a custom network or not.

Thanks to @Mephalich on the Redis community Discord for his help in understanding this. :-)

So, the solution is to not use `bind` nor `protected mode` and instead remove the `ports: - "6379:6379"` directive from my docker compose altogether. The addressing to Redis can then be either `redis://flowt-central-redis:6379` or just `redis://flowt-central-redis` (since 6379 is the default internal port anyway). Port 6379 is then not exposed on the host and, together with the firewall block, the Redis container is not reachable from the outside.

Well, I hope that is the end of the story anyway!

Murray